# Decimal symbol issue in MVC, C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, culture

I'm using MVC 5.0
I set the culture in config:

```
<system.web>
   <globalization uiCulture="fa-IR" culture="fa-IR" />
</system.web>
```

I have a model as the following:

```
public class MyModel
{
   [DisplayName("NbatPersent")]
   [Range(0, 100)]
   public double NbatPersent{ get; set; }
}
```

MVC shows the `NbatPersent` value in View like `22/5` and when I wanna submit form the form validator alert me `The field NbatPersent must be a number.`. It can't convert `22/5` to `22.5`
It will be OK if I enter 22.5 but if the property has a value it convert `.` to `/`

How can I convert all numeric properties' culture to `en-US` to show value like `22.5` not like `22/5`.

**Edit:**
I'm using `@Html.TextBoxFor` to show the decimal property because of user should be change it.

Comment: try this `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.NbatPersent,string.Format("{0:0.00}"));`

Comment: Do you have client side validation enabled. If so this this is a result of `jquery.validation.js`. You can use `jquery.globalize.js` to solve this. And there is no point changing `22/5` to `22.5` because then it will fail on the server when you submit the form unless you use a custom `ModelBinder`

Comment: @StephenMuecke How should we use `jquery.globalize.js`.

Comment: Have a look at [this article](http://blog.icanmakethiswork.io/2012/09/globalize-and-jquery-validate.html). You can also do this without using the plugin (manually changing the validator) and I will add an for that answer later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a client side validation error as a result of `jquery.validate.js` which uses the following to validate the value (which only allows the `.` character as the decimal separator.

```
number: function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(value);
},
```

You can use the `jquery.validate.globalize.js` plugin (refer [this article](http://blog.icanmakethiswork.io/2012/09/globalize-and-jquery-validate.html) for more detail) or you can add your own script to modify the validator, for example (include this after `jquery.validate.js`)

```
$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
   return this.optional(element) || $.isNumeric($(element).val().replace('/', '.'));
}
```

Comment: Side note:It would probably be better to to replace `$.isNumeric(...) bit` with the correct regex. For the last part would be `(?:/\d+)` but I don't know what the thousands separator for Farsi is, so not sure what `(?:,\d{3})+)` needs to be (i.e. what to use instead of `,`)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Globalize.culture is not a function` error

Comment: Are you using the plugin rather than the script in the answer?

Comment: Actually, I installed Globalize with jquery-globalize nuget package. http://blog.icanmakethiswork.io/2012/09/globalize-and-jquery-validate.html#comment-2277772998

Comment: I used that article and had no problems (but that was about 2 years ago). I'm not sure what you may have done wrong so you will need to ask a new question with the relevant code you have tried (but just using the script in my answer is easier and avoids needing to use the plugin)

Comment: Saved the day. Such a weird bug to deal with

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the view format explicitly

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => string.Format("{0:0.00}", x.NbatPersent));
```

else you can write a custom editor template for the double type (~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/double.cshtml):

```
@model double?
@Html.TextBox("", Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("#,##0.000#") : "")
```

and then in your view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.NbatPersent)
```

Comment: I'm using `@Html.TextBoxFor` to show the decimal property because of user should be change it.

Comment: I think it's not a correct way, I think we should change the MVC binding to correct this issue in all over the applications without changing the Helpers. Isn't it?

Comment: @MohammadDayyan  that and all depends up on your requirements .... Using attribute you can do it ......[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#,##0.000#}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public double? NbatPersent{ get; set; }

Comment: The OP has an *input* error. It's `EditFor` that will throw the exception, *not* `DisplayFor` or even `@Html.TextBox`. In fact, the suggested formats *depend* on having the correct culture - `.` is the *decimal placeholder*, it doesn't specify using  a dot as that placeholder