# "The decimal field must be a number"

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to find a possible easy solution for this issue. All the solutions found in web are not working for me. I have in my model a price field which can be a decimal value like 30,5 using comma. But the validation returns me an error "The 'field' must be a number".

I'm using the default validation used in MVC that I suppose it is using jQuery. Is there any way to avoid this issue?

The model code is:

```
 [Range(0.0, Double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Out of range")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Comment: are you sure that you can use comma? and not _dot_?

Comment: Comma. My default culture is es-ES

Comment: Did you set the culture? I forget how globalization runs in MVC-4

Comment: I have not set the culture. Using the thread instruction returns me spanish culture.

Comment: so, just try use _dot_ possibly mvc use _InvariantCulture_

Comment: Neither dot nor comma validates

Comment: can you provide a bit more code? sample model, controller, and how you use it

Comment: I suspect Chris Pratt's answer address your issue (i.e. its a client side validation issue because of your culture). Refer also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808687/decimal-symbol-issue-in-mvc-c/32817448#32817448) for an option of modifying the validator to accept an alternative decimal separator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the error is coming from client-side validation, not server-side. If it actually got to the server, you should be fine having the culture specified. However, ASP.NET's unobtrusive validation actually use the jQuery Validation plugin, and as you can see here at the [documentation page for the `number` validator](http://jqueryvalidation.org/number-method), only a `.` as the decimal separator will validate. You may simply have to remove the number validation rule from the field.

```
$("#Price").rules("remove", "number");
```

**UPDATE**

This post may help you: http://blog.icanmakethiswork.io/2012/09/globalize-and-jquery-validate.html. It explains how to essentially monkey-patch jQuery Validation to actually pay attention to culture.

Comment: The link is dead!

Comment: I think the dead link is now https://blog.johnnyreilly.com/2012/09/globalize-and-jquery-validate.html